# Oxmetrics, Matrices as input in loglikelihood function (GARCH)

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to write a program in Oxmetrics that estimates a multivariate GARCH model.
My multivariate GARCH model has the unconditional covariance matrix (should be the X variable) as input, but i'm unsure about how to correctly specify the correct matrix at each iteration.

My program looks as follows for now:

```
//Global variable; visible also in the likelihood function

decl X;


//Likelihood contributions

garch_likelihood_contributions(likval_t, par)

{

//Local variables
decl covar, lik, H,C,A, i;

//Parameters
C   = par[0];
A   = par[1];


//conditional covariance sequence
 H          = constant(.NaN,2,2);
 H          = C*C'+ exp(-A)*H[0][]+A*exp(-A)*X[0][];
 H[][0] = 0;            //Initial value  
 X[][0] = sumc(covar[m])/2071;   // Not correct specified yet, should be the    sample average of the covariance matrices // 

for(decl i=1; i<columns(X); ++i)

    {

        H[0][i] = C*C'+ exp(-A)*H[i-1][]+A*exp(-A)*X[i-1][];

    }

//likelihood contributions
lik    = constant(.NaN,columns(X),1);                   

  lik[0]    = 0.5*log(determinant(H[][i-1]))+  0.5*X[1][]*invert(H[][i-1])*X[1][]';
  for(decl i=1;i<2071;++i)
    {

        lik[i]  = 0.5*log(determinant(H[][i-1])) +  0.5*X[i-1][]*invert(H[][i-1])*X[i-1][]'; // her stod X[i+1]
    }
 //   adFunc[0]     = lik;
 //   return !ismissing(adFunc[0]);
 }

  decl likval_t; 
    //Return vector of likelihood-contributions
    likval_t[0] = lik;

//Return success
return 1;
}

//Likelihood function
garch_likelihood(par, likval, avScore, amHessian)
{
//Local variables
decl likval_t;

//Likelihood contributions
garch_likelihood_contributions(&likval_t, par);

//Return likelihood-value
likval[0] = double(sumc(likval_t));

//Return success
return 1;
}

main()
{
//Declare variables
decl data;
decl loglik, par;
decl C, A, covar;
decl vol, r, S_t, K, P;

//Load data:

data    = loadmat("covariances.in7")';
P       = data[0][0:];

covar = data[0:1][0:];


 X          = constant(.NaN,2,2);
 for (decl i = 0, i < columns(P), i+2    )
  {
   j[i] = <0,2;0,2>
   X[i]= vech(j[i]);

   }

//Initial values for parameters
par      = 0.1|0.5;                 //i.e. (omega, alpha, beta).    Try out different starting values!

//Settings for likelihood estimation
MaxControlEps(1e-6,1e-4);       
MaxControl(20000, 1, 1);   

//Maximize likelihood function
print("\n\n","Maximizing likelihood: \n");
MaxBFGS(garch_likelihood, &par, &loglik, 0, 1);

print("%r",{"C","A"}
   ,"%c",{"MLE"},
    par);
println("\nMaximized likelihood: ", loglik);
}
```

Inside the main, you should noticed that I have tried to specify the variable X as a 2x2 matrix for each iteration. The idea is that for each i, the loop should allocate the 2 first cloumns and rows from the datasheet "covariances.in7" into X.
The step for the loop should be 2, such that i = 1,3,5,7 ect.

Please post your thoughts, it's really appreciated.

Best regards,

Kristian

Answer (score 0):

I'm now aware that I need to write the following to get my loop to consider every second observation;

```
X          = constant(.NaN,2,2);
for (decl i = 0, i < columns(P), ++i    )
{
j[i] = <0,2;0,2>
X[i]= vech(j[i]);
i=i+1;
}
```